# C++ Constructor Initialize Non Primitive Member Variables In Stack

Tags: c++

I've a basic question about C++ constructors.

Let's say that I have a class definition something like this:

```
class Project {
public:
    int time;
    std::vector<Task> tasks;

    Project();
};
```

I want to initialize this vector in my source file, however I'm not sure about the correct and efficient way to do this.

```
Project::Project() {
    time = 0;
    tasks = std::vector<Task>();
}
```

Is this a correct way to initialize object in the stack?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the stack"?

Comment: No. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains [how do initialize class members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), and read that chapter.

Comment: @Frank By "stack", I mean "not in the heap".

Comment: @MertAkozcan You don't even know if Project is being allocated in the stack or the heap. Are you asking how can you have variable-sized storage of an object without incuring a secondary allocation?

Comment: 1) A hint: you are not initializing a vector, you are assigning it a new value after it has been initialized previously. 2) `tasks` is a member variable, therefore it will be stored wherever the `Project` instance is (stack/heap). However, vector's elements will be always stored on heap. You might want to look for small buffer optimization, e.g., Boost's small/static vectors and similar solutions, if you want to avoid heap allocations.

Comment: whether it is allocated on the heap or on the stack is (usually) not the objects buisness

Comment: Use the initialisation list for initializing members (whenever you can - which is most of the time), *not* the constructor body.

Comment: Interesting fun fact: It is unusual to see it done, but C++ can be implemented without stacks or heaps.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors can use custom allocators, so you may be able to use a vector class specialized for a custom allocator (like [this one](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html)).

However, you cannot use the stack of the constructor itself, as it becomes invalidated after the constructor finishes. You either need to allocate the memory in the object itself (in the linked example, make the `arena` a member of the class) or receive it as a parameter to the constructor.